# Too many posit. arguments and no value for argument python OOP

Tags: python, oop, pygame

Hi Im just starting to learn OOP and I use python to do so. Recently I ve been trying to code a game. I ve declared class Character that should be general and from that class my other classes will inherit. Now Im trying to create a class Player, I want to inherit everything but 1 variable. Here is a code:

```
class Character:
def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
    self.width = width
    self.height = width
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.vel = 3
    self.right = False
    self.left = False
    self.walk_count = 0
    self.is_jump = False
    self.jump_count = 10
    self.standing = True

class Player(Character):
def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, right, left, walk_count, is_jump, jump_count, standing):
    super().__init__(x, y, width, height, right, left, walk_count, is_jump, jump_count, standing)
    self.vel = 5
```

in super() I keep getting pylint error:

> Too many positional arguments for method call.

But I think it lets me run it even with it.

Also I want to put in only self.x, self.y, self.width and self.height when initializing, should I declare these values in class Player or let it be in class Character?

Then here I try to create an instance of class Player:

```
man = Player(200,410,64,64)
```

> And I got errors missing value for argument right, left, walk_count,
> is_jump, jump_count, standing

I tought that if i set values for them in class Character that I dont need to put values in when creating instance, because I want to set them to default values at the creation and then I will change them if I need it.

Later I will add class Enemy that will inherit most of the parameters from class Character also.

Comment: If you don't want to pass values to the `__init__` function, why do you declare the function to take these arguments in the first place? Also `Character`'s init only takes 4 arguments, yet you are trying to pass a lot more (way too many to make sense IMO)

Comment: You are right Ive had false understeanding of the whole class declaration. I tought that I need to put all values that I want to initialize in Player class to __init__ and then call super() to inherit them from class Character. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then, you must call the `super` method with the signature (number of parameters) desired.

Change

```
def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, right, left, walk_count, is_jump, jump_count, standing):
    super().__init__(x, y, width, height, right, left, walk_count, is_jump, jump_count, standing)
    self.vel = 5
```

to

```
def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
    super().__init__(x, y, width, height)
    self.vel = 5
```

Or, if you prefer, change Character's `__init__` to match the Player's `super` call, and change:

```
class Character:
def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
```

to

```
class Character:
def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, right, left, walk_count, is_jump, jump_count, standing):
```

and leave the `super` call as is.

The best approach is to only pass what is needed. If the only needed values to parameterize your Character object are `x,y,height,weight`, then you should only pass them - the remaining will be set automatically (you don't need to give them as input, since they will be discarded).

So, the correct approach is the first I mentioned.

Comment: Thank you it works! ... Could you please explain more to me? I tought that in super() I put every value that I want to inherit from the main class (Character)

Comment: No. In `super` you put every parameter you want to pass to the main class. Then, main class will parameterize them. But since your main class does not have an `__init__` that can handle that number of parameters, it will not work. If you add the to Character' `__init__`  the same parameters you use in Players' `super` function call, it will also work!

Comment: By the way, if this answer is correct mark it as Accepted right answer.